# How to avoid `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Instrumentation.IInstrumentationEventProvider` is not referenced?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dll

In my mvc3 project when it start Debugging it always shows this error message.

> The type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Instrumentation.IInstrumentationEventProvider'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I install  microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.common.dll this file also.But it shows that error again and again.

How can i slove this problem?Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you ensure that you have the right version of the Enterprise library. If you have installed enterprise library of other version, you may get this kind of exception.

Also check in the `References` of your application to ensure that the reference is in place.

Also, try to clean up the `Temporary ASP.Net files` and then clean and rebuild the solution and post the update.

Comment: i check the version number both are same.

Comment: @r.vengadesh: Did you check the references and try rebuilding the application after a clean operation

Comment: In references already microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.common file is their.But new one is not added in the references.

Comment: @r.vengadesh: what do you mean here by a new one.

Comment: @r.vengadesh: Please remove the reference for the old dll file and then add reference to the new dll file. If necessary, clean / remove all the files from bin and then `rebuild` the entire project

Comment: I add the new reference file c->windows->system32.But it is not working.How to add reference file?

Comment: try to uninstall the older version and then add the newer version to the project using the `Add Reference` dialog

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue..

I replaced with proper dll files but during compile time, it was throwing error.

Finally, I figured out.. I had to delete all the reference dll files that were part of enterprise library and added them again.  After doing this, it worked.

Comment: That saved a lot of time and effort Thank you Bro:)